# How to get Windows 7 back after installing Ubuntu (Linux)

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, ubuntu

My friend borrowed my laptop for a while and when he gave it back he said he replaced Windows 7 with Ubuntu. I asked him to switch it back simply because I prefer Windows. He claims not to know how. I don't want to go buy a new windows 7 disc I just want to figure out how to get rid of this Ubuntu and Windows 7. If anyone knows a way please let me know...

Comment: Did he completely format the hard drive when he installed Ubuntu or did he leave the W7 installation intact?

Comment: Make your friend buy you a new Windows 7 disk.

Answer (score 3):

If you can find somebody who has a Windows 7 disk that you could borrow, you could install Windows 7 using that, then activate it with the key on your laptop. If you don't have access to anybody else's disk, you could burn one yourself by downloading a Windows 7 ISO. While Microsoft does not offer an official location to download disk images of Windows 7 from them, DigitalRiver provides the official ISO downloads for people who buy copies of Windows 7 online, and no password is required to access the downloads, you just have to find them. I'm sure you could find them if you spent a little time on google.

The other solution is to make your friend buy you a Windows 7 disk. You don't need to buy a full license, just the install media. Most OEMs offer a way to order installation media from them for a nominal charge, usually $10-$20. If they borrowed your laptop, it's their responsibility to return it to you in the same working order that they received it, so if you can't find an installation disk, it seems reasonable to expect them to get you one.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried [UNetBootIn](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), a program that is supported on Linux. I recommend using a Windows .iso file with UNetBootIn, and running in off your USB Drive or a Compact Disc. From there, when you boot your computer, boot using the USB/Disc. It should go through the Windows installation.

PAY CLOSE ATTENTION.

You'll need to look on the underside of your laptop for a product key if you bought it with Windows Pre-Installed, then there should be a product code. It should be around like 25 digits. The installation process will ask for it, and since it isn't in use currently, then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, what happens when you boot? When you go into a directory explorer that shows the filesystem ubuntu is installed on is there another drive? Please provide more info.